# How to save old Messages on a Mac?

Tags: messages, data-recovery

i have all my old conversations from Messenger on my Mac (and not on my iphone). As I want to put the upcoming High Sierra on a previously deleted Mac instead of simply updating my Mac I wonder if it is possible to somehow save the old conversations. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

iMessage conversations appear to be saved in `~/Library/Messages`.

To see your Library folder, you'll need to use Go > Go to Folder... (⇧⌘G) and then type in `~/Library`. If your new Mac doesn't have any messages on it, you should be able to just copy the folder over (but make sure Messages is closed while doing it).

**Make sure to back up the destination Messages folder before copying if you are worried about losing data** (just rename it Messages-Old or something). If everything works okay, you can trash it afterward.